# What event should I use to detect parent JFrame closing in custom JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I have a custom [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) placed in a [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) (Well placed in a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) on a [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)). I have used [setDefaultCloseOperation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) to set my [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) to  [`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE).

My custom component has a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that continues to run after the frame has been closed. I know I could add a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to the [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and then make a call to the custom component to stop, but I would prefer to have my component be completely encapsulated. Is there any event I can use to detect when the parent [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) has been closed from within my [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html)?

Comment: DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE should be HIDE or NOTHING by using WindowListener, inside desired event should be called setVisible(false)

Comment: @mKorbel Why should it be HIDE or NOTHING? Disposal of the frame is what I want to happen when I close. If I do implement a WindowListener in my JFrame class I would call setVisible(false) but I am trying to avoid doing that. If I implement a WindowListener in my custom component it does not seem a good idea to manage the JFrame from there.

Comment: @mKorbel Oh wait, I think I may have just caught your implication. Will a WindowListener not be called if I use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Have you class implement the `windowClosing` event of the `WindowListener`.
2. Add an `AncestorListener` to your custom component and listen for the `ancestorAdded` event. This event is generated when you add your component to a visible GUI or when the GUI containeing your comonent is realized.
3. In the `ancestorAdded` event you add your WindowListener to the frame. You can get the current frame by using the `SwingUtilties.windowForComponent(...)` method.

Now all the logic is self contained in your class.

Comment: Yes, this seems a perfect solution. I will implement and if it works I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this code.

`frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
            //here other actions

          }
        }
);`

where frame is the object of your JFrame

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `HierarchyListener`:

```
//@see javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicProgressBarUI.java
class Handler implements ChangeListener, PropertyChangeListener, HierarchyListener {
    // we don't want the animation to keep running if we're not displayable
    @Override public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent he) {
        if ((he.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) != 0) {
            if (progressBar.isIndeterminate()) {
                if (progressBar.isDisplayable()) {
                    startAnimationTimer();
                } else {
                    stopAnimationTimer();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component needs to react to some kind of event it must implement some kind of listener - so why not make your component implement WindowListener and register it with the owner JFrame?

Comment: That would work, but how could I get access to the owner JFrame? Checking the parents recursively for a JFrame would be possible I suppose, but there is not yet a parent in the constructor.

Comment: There's no need to reference the JFrame from the component  - just make the Component implement WindowListener and when adding it to the JFrame (or the JPanel) call `myFrame.addWindowListener(myComponent)` and it'll be notified of the events.

Comment: That is not a self contained solution though. See camickr's answer.